# Unexpected T_Variable in a string which should be correct

Tags: php

Here's my string, I don't see how to resolve the issue?

```
print "<script> $(window).load(function(){$('#vid" . $l . "').hide();});</script>";
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic debugging and could be resolved by using a decent IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the double quotes, it's trying to parse the $ as variables. There's two ways to get around it:

Escape the `$`:

```
print "<script> \$(window).load(function(){\$('#vid" . $l . "').hide();});</script>";
```

Or use single quotes:

```
print '<script> $(window).load(function(){$("#vid' . $l . '").hide();});</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is trying to interpret the '$' as a variable but it doesn't like '(' as a var name.
you could try this way so it knows you want to output a literal dollar sign:
`print '<script> $(window).load(function(){$(\'#vid' . $l . '\').hide();});</script>';`

Answer (score 0):

Your `$(window)` is being interpreted as a request to interpolate a PHP variable into your string. Escape the `$` with a `\` or use single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Is either print() with parenthesis or echo, like:

```
print ('<script> $(window).load(function(){$("#vid' . $l . '").hide();});</script>');
```

or

```
echo '<script> $(window).load(function(){$("#vid' . $l . '").hide();});</script>';
```

This way it doesn't look for variables.

Comment: Why the -1? I tried it and it works perfectly...

Comment: Because `print()` [does not stop variable interpolation](http://3v4l.org/bGiEO).

Comment: Got it. You are right.